# Find not returning index for given value in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, self-organizing-maps

While writing a code for self organizing map neural network, I wrote codelet for finding euclidean distance between each neuron weight and each training input. Then I used compet function to make element with maximum distance value as 1 and rest zero (sparse matrix).

In other words each row has to have at least one element as 1.
But when I ran a loop to find indices of such elements in each row using find function, I got an empty matrix. Here is the code extract.

```
euc=negdist(cluster,x_train);
comp=compet(euc);
for i=1:10
ind=find(comp(i,:)==1);
m=mean(x_train(:,ind),2);
label(ind)=i;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [`compet`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/compet.html) will return a matrix of zeroes and ones where each *column* is guaranteed to have a `1` in it, not each row. In your code, you are extracting *rows* with the line `comp(i,:)`, and some of those rows don't have any ones, so `find` returns `[]`. You need to swap your indices to `comp(:,i)`.

I would also double-check the indices you use after that for `x_train` to make sure you haven't gotten them flipped either.